# How to evaluate the following integral

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fractional-calculus

Would anyone please let me know how to compute the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a\log(t^2+1)}{t^2 + a^2}dt,$$
here $a > 0$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BLog%5Bt%5E2+%2B+1%5D%2F%28t%5E2+%2B+a%5E2%29%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D&dataset=

Answer (score 1):

It equals $2a\Re \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log(t+i)}{t^2+a^2}dt$. We think that $\log$ is defined in the upper half-plane.  Then the contour may be closed to an upper halfplane, since integrated function is $o(1/|z|)$ for large $z$. We get $$2\pi i\, {\rm Res}_{ai} \frac{\log(z+i)}{z^2+a^2}=2\pi i\frac{\log((a+1)i)}{2ai}=\pi a^{-1}(\log(a+1)+i\pi/2),$$
taking real part and multiplying by $2a$ we get $2\pi\log(a+1)$.

Comment: Initial answer was both too sophisticated and wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica says $2\pi \log(1+a).$ If I had to guess about how it does it, I would say, make the substitution $t=a u,$ then differentiate the integrand with respect to $a$ to get a rational function, then integrate the answer with respect to $a.$

Comment: It looks too clever for Mathematica, I would rather suppose that it uses residues as me. Residues are more technological.

Comment: Usually Mathematica uses series expansions.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov For definite integrals? I don't think so. In the early days, it used a grab-bag of techniques, in the last twenty years, thanks to Oleg Marichev, it is more "scientific", and there are some formal transform calculus methods - I don't know the details.